# Spring @Async saving searches

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, search

I've got a search input field in my Java Spring based website where user can search for content of the website. I want to save the queries entered by users to my MySQL database asynchronously for autocomplete functionality. I know I can use the @Async annotation in Spring specifying a pool-size with the following:

```
<task:annotation-driven executor="executor" />
<task:executor id="executor" pool-size="100"/>
```

**Question:**

- Is this a good solution for a high traffic website with over 10,000 search per minute ? Considering the possibility of getting pool exhaustion exception ?
- Is there a better solution ?

Comment: Saving a search query and fetching for autocomplete doesn't seem like a heavy task to me (as long as you get your indexing right). I don't think using executor is necessary, I would just use plain DAO hooked up to a Controller

Comment: Yep, I'm using SOLR for indexing. I'm calling QueryService.save in my Controller and after that I call QueryService.query to query SOLR. I just thought that QueryService.save might effect the performance a little. So I'm wrong ?

Comment: I would think you could have an unbounded queue that you add your text to on each request (not in the background), and have a couple of background threads that consume from the queue when there is text available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [ThreadPoolTaskExecutor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html). When all threads in the pool are busy your job will just be queued until a thread is available. The maximum queue capacity and number of threads can be adjusted via `queueCapacity` / `maxPoolSize` property (`queueCapacity` defaults to INTEGER.MAX_VALUE).

One the thing you have to be concerned about is memory exhaustion. If you set your queue capacity too high and your job ran for too long, all the jobs can stack up in the queue eating up memory.

Also consider denial of service. An hacker can perform attack by filling up all the queue (hence denying genuine user's job from running)

So I'd say yes this is a good approach in the sense your Controller don't have to wait until the job is done, however consider how much memory each queued jobs take, how much memory space you have, how long it will run etc.

Good approach is just to best-guess some value, and setup a good thread pool / queue monitoring / statistics and adjust it over time.

Comment: I'm basically just trying to save the search queries entered by the user. Saving all the searches is not important. So if I set the pool size to 100 and if something goes wrong with the pool maybe I should restart the pool. Maybe somehow save all the existing thread in a list and them close them if something goes wrong. Would that be a good solution you think ?